# Push method displayed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, methods, push

I have an issue with this code. I want to push the odds number in a array called number. But when I display it with document.write it doesn't print out the way it supposed to. Please help!!
Here's what it displays: 11,31,3,51,3,5,71,3,5,7,9 instead of: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Trial</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var number = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var x = 2 * i + 1;
            number.push(x);
            document.write(number)
        };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So your expected output is `1,3,5,7,9`? You included even numbers in your question's output.

Comment: You should place write method out of the loop to get it called once not in every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put documet.write() after for loop. You are actually writing array of numbers at each stage.

```
var number= [];
var i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) 
    {var x =2*i+1;
     number.push(x);

    };
document.write(number)
```